# How to count how many 'banana's are there in a string in C, but one letter has to be capitalized?

Tags: c

I am supposed to make a function to count how many times the word "banana" appears in an input string. If there isn't even one, the function should return the value zero, and if there is one or more, the function should the according number. Also the word "banana" has to have one capitalized letter, doesn't matter which one. The program doesnt actually have to count the word banana itself, but rather count if there are letters in the string out of which u can make 'banana', and how many 'banana's could you make is the number that is returned.

I have written the code, but the function always returns the value 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getInput(char array[], int size) {
    char character = getchar();
    
    if (character == '\n') {
        character = getchar();
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (i < size - 1 && character != '\n') {
        array[i] = character;
        i++;
        character = getchar();
    }
    array[i] = '\0';
}

int countBananas(const char *str) {
    int i;
    int countA = 0, countB = 0, countN = 0, uppercaseCount = 0, A = 0, B = 0, N = 0;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 'A' || str[i] == 'a') {
            countA++;
            if (str[i] == 'A') {
                uppercaseCount++;
            }
        }

        if (str[i] == 'B' || str[i] == 'b') {
            countB++;
            if (str[i] == 'B') {
                uppercaseCount++;
            }
        }

        if (str[i] == 'N' || str[i] == 'n') {
            countN++;
            if (str[i] == 'N') {
                uppercaseCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (countB >= 1 && countA >= 3 && countN >= 2 && uppercaseCount != 0) {
        if (countB % 1 == 0 && countA % 3 == 0 && countN % 2 == 0) {
            countA = 0, countB = 0, countN = 0;

            for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                if (str[i] == 'A' || str[i] == 'a') {
                    countA++;
                    if (countA == 3) {
                        A++;
                        countA = 0;
                    }
                }

                if (str[i] == 'B' || str[i] == 'b') {
                    countB++;
                    if (countB == 1) {
                        B++;
                        countB = 0;
                    }
                }

                if (str[i] == 'N' || str[i] == 'n') {
                    countN++;
                    if (countN == 2) {
                        N++;
                        countN = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (A < B && A < N) {
                return A;
            } else if (B < A && B < N) {
                return B;
            } else if (N < A && N < B) {
                return N;
            } else if (A == B && A == N) {
                return A;
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    getInput(str, 100);

    int result = countBananas(str);
    printf("%d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest you use `fgets()` instead of `getchar()`.

Comment: Please revise question with sample input.

Comment: I would probably use `strcasecmp()` then check if  a match then check if there is one capitalized letter  in the potential match.

Comment: the program doesnt actually have to count the word banana itself, but rather count if there are letters in the string out of which u can make banana and how many bananas could you make is the number that is returned.

Comment: You want to edit your question to say that.  It's not at all clear from the question that you want to count letters then figure out how many times you can create the word banana out of that those letters with at least one letter upper case.

Comment: Isn't this the bin packing problem?  I.e. NP-hard

Comment: You count number of letters, if you have the right frequency (1, 3, 2) to zero them out so how would you recover how many times you could do this?  So then you count them again?

Comment: The input string Banana returns 1 so I can't reproduce your claims.

Comment: What's should result be for "BAnana"?  Is it exactly 1 upper case letter or at least 1?

Comment: It should be at least one upper case letter. So the result should be 1.

Comment: What about "BAnanabanana"?  Is that that 1 or 2?

Comment: that is 2, since i can take one uppercase letter per word, Banana and bAnana.

Comment: Please add those test cases to the question and revise the title and first part to talk about letter frequency.  I still think you end with bin packing so trying all combinations to find out the maximum you can get.

Comment: Since "banana" has 1 "b", 2 "n"s and 3 "a"s, the number of "banana" words we can construct regardless of case is `bananas = min(count_of_b, count_of_n/2, count_of_a/3)`, where counts are case-insensitive. The final answer is `answer = min(bananas, count_of_B + count_of_N + count_of_A)`, where counts are for capital letters only.

Comment: We have [B]An[ana]ba[na]na, [B]An[ana]ba[n]an[a], [B]An[ana]bana[na], [B]An[an]ab[ana]na, [B]An[an]ab[an]an[a], [B]An[an]ab[a]na[na], [B]An[an]aban[ana], ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
    void inputString(char array[], int size) {
        char character = getchar();
        if (character == '\n') character = getchar();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < size - 1 && character != '\n') {
            array[i] = character; // STRING INPUT
            i++;
            character = getchar();
        }
        array[i] = '\0';
    }
    
    int countBananas(const char *str) {
        int i;
        int letterA = 0, letterB = 0, letterN = 0, uppercaseLetter = 0, uppercaseUsed = 0, sets = 0;
    
        for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (str[i] == 'A' || str[i] == 'a') {
                letterA++;
    
                if (str[i] == 'A') {
                    uppercaseLetter++;
                }
            }
    
            if (str[i] == 'B' || str[i] == 'b') {
                letterB++;
                if (str[i] == 'B') {
                    uppercaseLetter++;
                }
            }
    
            if (str[i] == 'N' || str[i] == 'n') {
                letterN++;
    
                if (str[i] == 'N') {
                    uppercaseLetter++;
                }
            }
    
            if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') {
                uppercaseUsed = 1;
            }
        }
    
        if (letterB >= 1 && letterA >= 3 && letterN >= 2 && uppercaseLetter != 0 && uppercaseUsed) {
            while (letterA >= 3 && letterB >= 1 && letterN >= 2) {
                letterA -= 3;
                letterB -= 1;
                letterN -= 2;
                sets++;
            }
            return sets;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    int main() {
        char input[100];
        printf("Enter some string: ");
        inputString(input, 100);
    
        int result = countBananas(input);
        printf("%d", result);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's weird that you are asking for help, got two answers that you didn't comment on and then write up your own answer that you accept.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the algorithm that @n.m.couldbeanAI shared.  We count many times we have the expected frequency of letters regardless of case but ensure it's no longer than number of upper case letters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 100
#define LETTERS "ABNabn"

int min(size_t n, int *vals) {
    int min = *vals;
    for(size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if(vals[i] < min)
            min = vals[i];
    return min;
}

void str_freq(const char *str, const char *letters, int *freq) {
    memset(freq, 0, sizeof *freq * strlen(letters));
    for(; *str; str++) {
        char *found = strchr(letters, *str);
        if(found)
            freq[found - letters]++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char str[LEN];
    if(!fgets(str, LEN, stdin))
        return 1;
    int freq[sizeof LETTERS - 1];
    str_freq(str, LETTERS, freq);
    printf("%d\n",
        min(2, (int []) {
            min(3, (int []) {
                (freq[0] + freq[3]) / 3, // [Aa]
                freq[1] + freq[4],       // [Bb]
                (freq[2] + freq[5]) / 2  // [Nn]
            }),
            freq[0] + freq[1] + freq[2]  // [ABN]
        })
    );
}
```

and example runs:

```
$ ./a.out
banana
0
$ ./a.out
Banana
1
$ ./a.out
BAnanabanana
2
```

Comment: We have [B]An[ana]ba[na]na, [B]An[ana]ba[n]an[a], [B]An[ana]bana[na], [B]An[an]ab[ana]na, [B]An[an]ab[an]an[a], [B]An[an]ab[a]na[na], [B]An[an]aban[ana], ...

Comment: @LajosArpad No idea what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: I'm telling you that you have more than two matches in your third example.

Comment: @LajosArpad Then you assume you can use the same letter more than once.  That assumption is incorrect based on my reading of the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

This is how one can achieve this goal, if we are allowed to bypass elements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int bananaSearcher(char * input, char *bananaString, int inputIndex, int alreadyCapital) {
    if (alreadyCapital && (*bananaString == '\0')) {
        return 1;
    }
    int counter = 0;
    char current;
    while ((current = *(input + inputIndex++)) != '\0') {
        if ((current == *bananaString) || ((!alreadyCapital) && (current == toupper(*bananaString)))) {
            counter += bananaSearcher(input, bananaString + 1, inputIndex, alreadyCapital || (current == toupper(*bananaString)));
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {
    char * banana = "banana";
    char * input = "B32ananaBbAananadskljsd";
    printf("%d", bananaSearcher(input, banana, 0, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

For an input of **B32ananaBbAananadskljsd**, the output is 34 with the following variations:

```
0 3 4 5 6 7 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 6 11 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 6 13 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 6 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 12 13 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 12 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 7 12 13 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 7 12 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 7 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 11 12 13 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 11 12 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 11 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 6 7 12 13 
B a n a n a 
0 3 6 7 12 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 6 7 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 6 11 12 13 
B a n a n a 
0 3 6 11 12 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 6 11 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 6 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 3 12 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 5 6 7 12 13 
B a n a n a 
0 5 6 7 12 15 
B a n a n a 
0 5 6 7 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 5 6 11 12 13 
B a n a n a 
0 5 6 11 12 15 
B a n a n a 
0 5 6 11 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 5 6 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 5 12 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 7 12 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
0 11 12 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
8 11 12 13 14 15 
B a n a n a 
9 10 12 13 14 15 
b A n a n a
```

For an input of **BAnanabanana**, the output is 10, the possibilities are:

```
0 3 4 5 8 9 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 8 11 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 5 10 11 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 7 8 9 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 7 8 11 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 7 10 11 
B a n a n a 
0 3 4 9 10 11 
B a n a n a 
0 3 8 9 10 11 
B a n a n a 
0 5 8 9 10 11 
B a n a n a 
0 7 8 9 10 11 
B a n a n a
```

Explanation:

- we have `input`, a string
- and `bananaString` where we prefill the lower-case "banana" string
- as well as `inputIndex`, so we know where we were
- and `alreadyCapital`, to keep track of the criteria that exactly one letter was capital
- if we reached the end of `bananaString` and we had exactly one capital (otherwise we would not reach this point), then we have a solution and we stop
- otherwise

  - we initialize `counter` with 0, which is the neutral element of the addition arithmetic operation
  - we create `current`, a character where we cache our current value
  - if `current` matches the current expected character of `bananaString` (if we had a capital letter already, then we do it case-sensitively, otherwise in a case-insensitive manner)

    - then we call `bananaSearcher` and add the number of solutions to `counter`

      - we pass `input`
      - and the next position of `bananaString` because we found the current one
      - the incremented `inputIndex` so we will know where we were
      - and we compute whether we already had the capital letter

Comment: You are answering the question "how many ways are there to make the word *banana* out of letters in the input". Others are answering a very different question, "how many copies of the word *banana* can be made out of letters in the input".